# What happens on buffer overflow?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, buffer

I read somewhere that every TCP connection has it's own 125kB output and input buffer. What happens if this buffer is full, and I still continue sending data on linux?

According to http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html the packets are just silently dropped, without notifying me. What can I do to stop this from happening? Is there any way to find out if at least some of my data has been sent correctly, so that I can continue at a later point in time?

Comment: Keep in mind, `send()` and the various flavors can be used for any type of socket, TCP or UDP.  A stream socket should block when the write buffer is full, while a UDP socket could (and will) drop it.

Comment: But I don't want it to block, I just want to retry if there's some space available again :)

Comment: Does blocking mean I have to wait for the other device to download the data and sends the answer: "Ok, I got the packet." or does blocking just block until linux sent them?

Comment: If you just want to "retry if there's space avaiable", then put your socket in non-blocking mode and use poll, select, or epoll.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a "packet" in TCP sockets. (There is at the lower TCP layer, but it's not exposed to the apps). TCP sockets are stream based. When you call "send", it doesn't sent the data as a packet. It sends it across several packets. The app receiving the data may not get all the data at once.

Comment: alright. Thank you for clearing things up to me ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is this. "send" calls on a TCP socket will just block until the TCP sliding window (or internal queue buffers) opens up as a result of the remote endpoint receiving and consuming data.  It's not much different than trying to write bytes to a file faster than the disk can save it.

If your socket is configured for non-blocking mode, send will return EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN, until data can be sent. Standard [poll](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html), [select](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html), and [epoll](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html) calls will work as expected so you know when to "send" again.

Comment: So I get EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN if the free space in the operation systems buffer is too small to handle my given buffer?

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt - Correct, assuming your socket is setup to be non-blocking. http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html

Comment: Good answer except that you have confused the congestion window with the sliding window. Change 'congestion' to 'sliding' throughout and you are OK. See for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congestion_window).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the "packets are dropped".  I think that what is more likely is that the calls that the program makes to write() will either block or return a failure.