# Receive/Send in single thread or separate threads?

Tags: c++, tcp, zeromq

I was in a discussion about  Multiple Threads in a client application and was told that using a separate thread for receiving data and another thread for sending data is not the way to go.

Why?

From what I know TCP is Full-Duplex so this would be a performance improvement, or not?

Comment: If you're just handling a a few sockets, it probably doesn't matter as your program will likely be I/O bound no matter what.  If you're planning to handle large numbers of clients, this is a good article about ways to do that efficiently:  http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a dedicated send thread and a dedicated receive thread is bad for two reasons.

First, it means that a context switch is required every time you go from receiving to sending unless you are doing both at the same time.

Second, it means that in the the typical path where you receive a query, formulate a response, and then send that response, data will need to be handed from one thread to another, blowing out caches.

That said, if performance isn't super-critical and it fits into your design well, it certainly works. It's just that there's usually no advantage.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it depends on the scale of your application. If you are doing a small app for a class project, it might be enough to have the send and receive on the same thread. Then you don't have to worry about threading issues.

However, I worked on an application that had to listen for several thousand incoming connections, and each connection might be sending a significant amount of data. We had a thread whose sole purpose was listening for socket connections and putting the new connections into a pool, and a variable number of threads (depending on how busy the app was) just for reading off of sockets, and a different pool of threads for writing.

The problem is that if your listening socket isn't reading the data off of the wire fast enough and the buffer fills up, an error is returned, and in the case of thousands of clients, caused there to be a lot of reconnects and re-sends of data, which compounded the problem that the data was not being read fast enough in the first place.

So it comes back to what I said in the first place - it depends on the scale of your application, but why not add in the ability now? Just make sure that you are thread safe, and you should be OK.

Comment: `The problem is that if your listening socket isn't reading the data off of the wire fast enough and the buffer fills up, new incoming packets are just dropped - lost forever.`
Lost ? How ? If the listener bound to your socket is doing his work fine, there are no such things like `dropped data`, at least using TCP. Regarding the rate at which your application should read on the socket is none of your responsability, TCP has a feature called `Window size` to deal with this.

Comment: 'If the listener bound to your socket is doing his work fine' Yes, you are correct, if the listener is doing fine...however in large scale apps with thousands (10,000 plus) of clients, each sending megabytes of data, I have seen the buffer fill up, and data get lost - there were packets of data that I know were sent on the client side that never made it to the application at the server. When the incoming buffer is full, then new incoming packets can be dropped. Maybe it was bad handling on the server end, but that was what we saw.

Comment: OK...here is what I was talking about: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269430/what-happens-on-buffer-overflow

The TCP socket sends back an error, which (in the case of the client app) caused it to lose data. Halim, you are quite right, the data dropping was not due to TCP, which at least notifies the apps that the error is happening, but it caused serious problems in the app when thousands of apps are trying to re-send. Bad design, in a couple of ways, but threading the reads helped out significantly.

Comment: I understand your point of view. However, if the packets are dropped because the socket size is running low, wouldn't the remote TCP stack resend later, at regular intervals these packets because they weren't correctly handled by the local stack ?

Comment: Halim, you are quite correct, and I edited the answer somewhat to clarify.

The problem can come when the sending app is transmitting something that needs to be an atomic send, that is, some of the data is not enough - all of it has to be received for the data to make sense, so the sending app got the error, and attempted to re-send the data, which is a LOT of data, which exacerbated the problem. Yes, there were architectural errors, and if the company had stayed afloat long enough, we might even have been able to fix them.

Comment: @Silas: That one application implemented an architecture in a broken way and suffered because of it doesn't mean there's anything wrong with that architecture. This is especially true where, as here, the problem flowed from misusing TCP and had nothing to do with their threading.